# how to open new window with widget in it?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am using GWT/ExtGWT. I have a little problem... I have an Hyperlink in my web page and when
the user clicks on this hyperlink, a new browser window should be
opened containing a widget (a widget made by me that contains a form
with textboxes, labels, comboboxes...). But I don't know how can I do
it. Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using hyperlink, try a text object, add  tags / css to make it look & feel like a hyperlink.. add an onClick event handler where something like this goes :

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.add(new NewWidget());
    dialog.show();
```

Or this if you prefer another look (but i think this is more complicated) :

```
    Window.open(url, name, features);
```